# How do I trim every leaf from an ArrayList implementation of a heap?

Tags: java, arraylist, heap

I'm trying to write a method that will trim all leaves from an ArrayList based heap implementation in Java. Right now I have this.

```
public void trimLeaves()
  {
  if(list.size() < 2) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
      if (list.get((2*i)+1) == null && list.get((2*i)+2) == null) {
          list.remove(i);
      }
  }
 }
```

I understand my error which is that the for loop will keep iterating to the original size even as the list gets smaller, but I'm not sure how to take that into account.

Comment: Note: ideally your question should come with a [mcve]. There might be all kinds of bugs hiding in this code.

Comment: Having said that, one *other* way to go about this: don't **iterate** and **manipulate** your list in the same loop. You could rather do: A) iterate the list as is, and **collect** all indexes with null values into ANOTHER list. B) then afterwards, you iterate the second list (probably starting from its end ;-) and remove the indexes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not that you keep iterating to the original size. In fact, you are actually getting the updated list size on every iteration. Your error is that you are looping until `i` reaches `list.size()` but you are attempting to get elements far beyond the end of the list by doing `list.get((2*i)+2)`. You need to iterate while `2*i + 2 < list.size()`.